# How to deploy EJB 2.0,JARs and EARs in Tomcat-OpenEJB?

Tags: tomcat, openejb, ejb-2.x

Is there any way to deploy EJBs,JARs or EARs in Tomcat-OpenEJB ?
If I donot want to use collapsed EAR concept or JEE6 .

Please reply..!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please update your question with the exact Tomcat and OpenEJB versions you are working with and what instructions you followed to deploy OpenEJB into Tomcat.  I'd recommend OpenEJB 3.1.4 and any Tomcat 5.5 or later.  Note, both OpenEJB and Tomcat support older versions of the Servlet and EJB APIs in the current releases.

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  Just drop them in the webapps directory.